# Encoding error after converting application into executable using py2exe and getting them from mysql (pySide, Python 3)

Tags: python, mysql, pyside, py2exe

I have an application that runs perfectly if I run it in directly from Python. However, after I turn it into an executable using py2exe the encoding "breaks".

I run some code that gets the string "Comitê" from a mysql server.
If i run the code:

```
fromMySql = getFromMysql()
local = "Comitê"
print(fromMySql)
print(local)
```

And save two files, one running directly from python, the other after compiling with py2exe, i get the following results:

```
FROM PYTHON:
    USING SUBLIME TEXT 3 -> REOPEN WITH ENCODING -> UTF-8:
        Comit?
        Comit?
    USING SUBLIME TEXT 3 -> REOPEN WITH ENCODING -> WESTERN (ISO 8859-1):
        Comitê
        Comitê

AFTER PY2EXE:
    USING SUBLIME TEXT 3 -> REOPEN WITH ENCODING -> UTF-8:
        Comit?
        Comitê

    USING SUBLIME TEXT 3 -> REOPEN WITH ENCODING -> WESTERN (ISO 8859-1):
        Comitê
        ComitÃª
```

It's worth noting that in the beginning of all my files I have:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

The code (removing unimportant bits):

Main window code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

import PySide.QtGui as QtGui

from ui.mainWindowComite_ui import Ui_MainWindowComite
import login
import connector as con

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindowComite):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindowComite.setupUi(self, self)
        self.actionCadastro.triggered.connect(self.abrirCadastro)
        self.actionDelegacao.triggered.connect(self.abrirDelegacao)
        self.actionAcompanhamento.triggered.connect(self.abrirAcompanhamento)
        self.actionInvestigacao.triggered.connect(self.abrirInvestigacao)
        self.actionHistorico.triggered.connect(self.abrirHistorico)
        self.login()

    def login(self):
        self.loginDialog = login.Login(self)
        self.loginDialog.setModal(True)
        self.loginDialog.show()
        self.loginDialog.rejected.connect(self.close)
        self.loginDialog.accepted.connect(self.autenticado)

    def autenticado(self):
        self.setor = self.loginDialog.setor
        print(self.setor)
        print("Comitê")
        if self.setor != "Comitê":
            QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, u"Erro", u"Esta versão do programa só pode ser utilizada pelo Comitê")
            self.close()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        con.close()
        event.accept()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("testê")
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The login class:

```
import PySide.QtGui as QtGui
import sys

from ui.login_ui import Ui_Login
import connector as con


class Login(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_Login):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Login.setupUi(self, self)

    def accept(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.setor = con.autenticar(self.setorLineEdit.text(),
                                      self.senhaLineEdit.text())
        if self.setor is not None: self.setor = self.setor["setor"]
        if self.setor is not None:
            QtGui.QDialog.accept(self)
        else:
            QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, "Falha", "Tente novamente, setor ou senha errada")
```

The connector class:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import datetime
import pymysql


def autenticar(login, senha):
    query = "Select setor FROM setores " \
            "WHERE login='%s' AND senha='%s'" % (login, senha)
    execute(query)
    setor = cur.fetchall()
    return setor[0] if len(setor)>0 else None

def connect():
    global cur, con
    con = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'database', autocommit=True)
    cur = con.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

def execute(query):
    try:
        cur.execute(query)
    except Exception as e:

        if str(e)[1:5] == '2013': # Lost connection to server
            cur.close()
            con.close()
            connect()
            cur.execute(query)
        else:
            raise e

def close():
    cur.close()
    con.close()

connect()
```

Comment: I've had some luck with reloading `sys` and then using `sys.setdefaultencoding` but that may be considered hackish depending on your environment.  Python 2, or Python 3?  If you declare your string as unicode and use the unicode escape for the character in question does that have any effect?  (IE: `u'\u0034'`)?

Comment: I managed to make it work converting everything to python 2 and then adding charset='utf8' pymysql's connect method. The same thing does not work in Python 3